# sed command to read the name of .js file from script call in html

Tags: html, sed

I want to read all .js files called from an HTML file. The following command reads but if there are other features in the call it does not read..

```
jsFiles=$(echo "$BODY" | sed -rn 's/<script\ssrc=\W(.*.js).*/\1/p')
```

For the above command, script file call should be like this:

```
<script src='js/default.js'></script>
```

The output:

```
js/default.js
```

How can I modify that it works for other options that script call may include?

For example;

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="'$lastJsLocation'" language="javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: suggestion: don't use sed, instead use html/xml parser like xmlstarlet or a programming language like perl/python along with html/xml module...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML is really that regular and the target sections are on 1 line at a time:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*<script.*src=["'\'']*\([^"'\'']*\).*/\1/p' file
js/default.js
$lastJsLocation
```

Comment: Hi, I want to also check this match ends with .js .. Where should I add it @Ed Morton

Comment: Add `\.js` before the last closing brace of the capture group, i.e. change `*\)` to `*\.js\)`. You should update your question though as it's not clear that that's a requirement and in particular your question (`How can I modify that it works for other options that script call may include?`) makes it sound like you DO want to print `$lastJsLocation` while with this new requirement in your comment means that you won't.

Answer (score 1):

I advise to use an XML parser to extract the value you want.

Given the HTML you want to parse are on files

```
 $ cat file1
 <script src='js/default.js'></script>
 $ cat file2
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="'$lastJsLocation'" language="javascript"></script>
```

If you have `xmllint` available, you can use this command:

```
 $ xmllint --xpath 'string(//script/@src)' file1
 js/default.js
 $ xmllint --xpath 'string(//script/@src)' file2
 '$lastJsLocation'
```

If you have `xmlstarlet`, you can use this command:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /script/@src -v . -n file1
js/default.js
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /script/@src -v . -n file2
'$lastJsLocation'
```

The `xmlstarlet` options seems complicated, but there aren't if you look at `xmlstartlet sel --help`. Partial output below:

> -T  - output is text (default is XML)
>   -t  - template 
>   -m  - match XPATH expression
>   -v  - print value of XPATH expression
>   -n  - print new line

Comment: I'm very interested in learning to use xmlstarlet and with that in mind - [the OP said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810044/sed-command-to-read-the-name-of-js-file-from-script-call-in-html/51810157#comment90671535_51810157) that she only wants to print the value if it ends in `.js`, how would you do that in xmlstarlet?

Comment: Also - though the script you posted works when there's only 1 "script" line in each input file it fails with `file:2.1: Extra content at the end of the document
<script  type="text/javascript" src="'$lastJsLocation'" language="javascript"></
^
` when both "script" lines are in one file. How do you use it for the normal case where there's multiple similar tags+values in an HTML file?

Comment: @EdMorton Comment2: In the _normal_ case (a HTML document for example), the `script` tags would be enclosed within a root tag. If you add a `<dummy>...</dummy>` tag and use the xpath `/dummy/script/@src`, that would work.

Comment: @EdMorton Comment1: As far as I know (and I'm no expert at all), this is not possible with xmlstarlet. If this tool would support Xpath 2.0, I would use this xpath `/dummy/script[end-with(@src,".js")]`. Unfortunately that doesn't work...

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, that make sense for Comment2 and too bad for Comment1 - do you know if xmllint can do that job? So far I haven't seen anything to really decide between the two tools and I definitely don't want to learn both or learn the inferior one.

Comment: @EdMorton I don't think xmllint can do this because it doesn't support xpath 2.0. I didn't find so far a "golden" command line xml parser. I often use either tool and pipe to sed or awk when parsing more complex xml file...

Comment: Got it, thanks. For my simple mind I probably need something that converts XML to/from CSV and then I can just analyze/modify the CSV with awk! I do fully appreciate the issues around that though (e.g. handling ad-hoc comments).